# Query resources using UID in kubernetes client-go

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I'm using the k8s [client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) library to mainly perform CRUD operations for CRDs.

Also, in kubernetes we have a unique [UID](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names/) for each resource.

So is there a way to query resources in kubernetes using this UID. If so can you please share any resources, code snippets which helpful for this??